# NG8008 doesn't appear for Angular 16 with required input that isn't set

Tags: angular, nomachine-nx, angular16

I just updated a bigger project, that uses NX to the latest version of Angular and as I love the required inputs I directly tried it out. While the IDE worked and showed an error, ng serve didn't show the error when a required input is set. Does anybody face the same issue?

Example for that:
The IconComponent has a required input icon.

```
@Input({
    required: true
  }) icon: string;
```

The IDE shows that the icon component has a required input "icon" which isn't set. That is exactly what I expect.

[image: IDE output]

However, the ng serve command / ng build command doesn't show an error:
[image: compiler output]
I would expect an error like described in the official angular docs.

My first guess was that this has something to do with a local angular cache, but I already tried deleting the .angular folder which didn't solve the issue.

I am using the following packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "16.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "16.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "16.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "16.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "16.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "16.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "16.1.7",
...
} 
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.1.6",
     "@angular-devkit/core": "16.1.6",
     "@angular-devkit/schematics": "16.1.6",
     "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.2",
     "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.2",
     "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.2",
      "@angular/cli": "~16.1.0",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.1.7",
     "@angular/language-service": "16.1.7",
    "@nx/angular": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/cypress": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/express": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/jest": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/linter": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/nest": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/node": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/storybook": "16.6.0",
    "@nx/workspace": "16.6.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "16.1.6"
}
```

My nx project.json looks like that:

```
"build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": ["libs/base-libs/frontend/stylesheets/src/lib"]
        },
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/project",
        "index": "apps/project/src/index.html",
        "main": "apps/project/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "apps/project/src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/project/tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [{
            "input": "licenses",
            "glob": "*.md",
            "output": "assets"
          }
        ],
        "styles": ["apps/project/src/styles.scss"],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "19mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            }
          ],
          "fileReplacements": [...],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    serve": {
          "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
```

Tsconfig also doesn't have anything special defined.
Unfortunally with a new project this problem is not happening. So it seems like this has something to do with a config defined in this project. Did anybody else face such a problem when using the required field for Angular inputs?

Comment: Probably due to nx cache ? Do nx reset will remove the cache.

Comment: Unfortunally nx reset also doesn't help with that problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work now. I reinstalled the node packages and updated my Node version, maybe that was the reason. Before I used npm in version 9.4.6 and updated to 9.6.7. So if anybody else faces this issue try to reinstall the node modules or update your npm version.